# Best paint (not spray) for outdoor plastic?

Tags: painting, paint

What's the best type of paint (not spray) for outdoor plastic? Something that will last almost forever and comes in gallon+ buckets, and is not cost-prohibitive?

Answer (score 1):

Krylon has a brush on for plastic paint in limited colors. It's their fusion brand.
I have no vested interest in this company and the picture is from there web site.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to find this anywhere though...

Comment: Sherwin Williams, Granger, and I think Lowes

Comment: Sometimes where you live will determine what you can get due to state limits on VOCs (or other components of the particular paint, but that's the common one I'm aware of.)